# ArrayList is Displaying Null even after pushing Data into it

Tags: android, asynchronous, arraylist, null

I have Globally Initialized Arraylist in Program, and Added the Latitude and Longitude from the JSON Data.In the **makeJsonPopularDestinationDetailPage()** the value are added in the ArrayList and it is quite good as i expected within the function.But when i try to access to the Another function ,it is showing null.Why the arraylist is not showing null?

**PopularDestinationGridDetail**

```
    private void makeJsonPopularDestinationDetailPage() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        String URL1 = Navigation_URL_Popular_Destination + "/1";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL1,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            //
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                            description = jsonObject.getString("description");
                            latitude = jsonObject.getString("latitude");
                            longitude = jsonObject.getString("longitude");
                            templeTitle.setText(title);
                            textDescription.setText(description);

                            destination_list_google_map.add(new ClassDestinationGoogleMap(latitude, longitude));
                            addMarker();


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

//
//                        System.out.println("Wow" + destination_list_google_map.get(0).getLatitude());
//                        System.out.println("Wow" + destination_list_google_map.get(0).getLongitude());




                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //  headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return headers;
            }

        };


        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }





    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        if (id == R.id.destination_button_gallery) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_changer_detaildestination, new FragmentImageGallery())
                    .commit();


            imageButtongallery.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.destination_circular_shape_icon_withclick));
            imageButtongallery.setImageResource(R.mipmap.destination_imagebutton_gallery_onclick);

            ButtonVideo.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.destination_circular_shape_icon_without_click));
            ButtonVideo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.destination_video_button_without_click);


            ButtonAudio.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.destination_circular_shape_icon_without_click));
            ButtonAudio.setImageResource(R.mipmap.destination_audio_button_without_click);


        } else if (id == R.id.destination_button_video) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_changer_detaildestination, new FragmentVideoDestination()).commit();


            imageButtongallery.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.destination_circular_shape_icon_without_click));
            imageButtongallery.setImageResource(R.mipmap.destination_imagebutton_gallery_without_click);

            ButtonVideo.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.destination_circular_shape_icon_withclick));
            ButtonVideo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.destination_video_button_onclick);


            ButtonAudio.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.destination_circular_shape_icon_without_click));
            ButtonAudio.setImageResource(R.mipmap.destination_audio_button_without_click);


        } else if (id == R.id.destination_button_audio) {

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_changer_detaildestination, new FragmentAudioDestination()).commit();

            imageButtongallery.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.destination_circular_shape_icon_without_click));
            imageButtongallery.setImageResource(R.mipmap.destination_imagebutton_gallery_without_click);

            ButtonVideo.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.destination_circular_shape_icon_without_click));
            ButtonVideo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.destination_video_button_without_click);


            ButtonAudio.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.destination_circular_shape_icon_withclick));
            ButtonAudio.setImageResource(R.mipmap.destination_audio_button_onclick);


        } else {

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_changer_detaildestination, new FragmentImageGallery())
                    .commit();

        }


    }


    void addMarker(){



        Double x = Double.valueOf(destination_list_google_map.get(0).getLatitude());
        Double y = Double.valueOf(destination_list_google_map.get(0).getLongitude());


        System.out.println("x"+x);
        System.out.println("y"+y);


        LatLng populardestination = new LatLng(x, y);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(populardestination).title("Suman"));
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(populardestination).zoom(15).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));





    }




    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        // System.out.println("object" + destination_list_google_map.get(position).getLatitude());

//        System.out.println("Wow" + destination_list_google_map.get(0).getLatitude());  *****why null, idon't get it
//        System.out.println("Wow" + destination_list_google_map.get(0).getLongitude());

//
        // destination_list_google_map.get(0).getLatitude();

//
//        Double x = Double.valueOf(27.6644);
//        Double y = Double.valueOf(85.3188);
//        Double x = Double.valueOf(destination_list_google_map.get(0).getLatitude());
//        Double y = Double.valueOf(destination_list_google_map.get(0).getLongitude());

        mMap = googleMap;


//        LatLng populardestination = new LatLng(x, y);
//        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(populardestination).title("Suman"));
//        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(populardestination).zoom(15).build();
//        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    }
```

**ClassDestinationGoogleMap**

```
public class ClassDestinationGoogleMap implements Serializable {

    public String latitude;
    public String longitude;

    public ClassDestinationGoogleMap(String lati, String longi) {
        latitude = lati;
        longitude = longi;


    }


    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
}
```

> I don't get the exact reason ,why it is showing null.Can anyone
>   explain it?

Comment: Need more code to figure this out

Comment: @kapsym updated check

Comment: Is `OnMapReady` one of the functions where you are not able to access the array?

Comment: @Shahim outside that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted, it seems likely that it is a timing issue.

i.e. the arrayList is being populated in the completion block of an HTTP request. And, you are trying to access the values in the arraylist during the `onMapReady` event.

The problem here is that, when onMapReady is called, it is more than likely that the Request has not yet completed, and your array is still null. So you need to ensure that the request has completed before accessing the arrayList.

For instance, if you want to add markers to the map, instead of doing it in onMapReady, you can create another function that will be called inside the request completion block:

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
  ...
  destination_list_google_map.add(new ClassDestinationGoogleMap(latitude, longitude));
  ...
  addMarkers();
}

...
...

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
  //save map object to variable
  mMap = googleMap;
}

void addMarkers() {
  //ArrayList will have values here
  Double x = Double.valueOf(destination_list_google_map.get(0).getLatitude());
  Double y = Double.valueOf(destination_list_google_map.get(0).getLongitude());

  LatLng populardestination = new LatLng(x, y);
  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(populardestination).title("Suman"));
}
```

Comment: yes man ,the size is given.

    void addMarker(){

       System.out.println("Addoing Marker"+ destination_list_google_map.size());

    }

Comment: the code to add markers can be put anywhere. The only condition is it must be called *AFTER* the response is received. So you can create the `addMarkers()` function in your activity and call it from the onResponse of your request.

Comment: In `onMapReady`, all you have to do is `mMap = googleMap`, which saves the map object into a variable. All the rest can be done inside `addMarker()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151334/discussion-between-seon-and-shahim).